# is contract.allEvents scalable for a metamask dapp?

Tags: solidity, web3js

In my dapp, I am calling contract.allEvents({from: 0, to: 'latest'}.

I am doing this for every user and every time they first enter the site.

Is this scalable? What if my contract gets to 1 million events? How long will take take to load? Are those 1 million individual requests?

Should I use web3.eth.filter instead?

I like the simplicity of allEvents over the "topics" method of filter but if it doesn't scale I guess I would have to change.

Answer (score -1):

When you call contract.allEvents, you will get receive events like data, changed, etc..,. Events will use storage as log's. I am not very sure how much time it will take to load in main network. Where is case of my local dev net I am getting 3-5 events for 1 sec.

Any how we will not load all 1 million events in a single page. We will use pagination to render 1 million req.

So I'll recommend use from and to block numbers for retrieve an events.